# {{#link-to ‘routeName’}} with dynamic context

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to use link-to with dynamic context params as a single variable?

This works when there is 1 dynamic part, but in the example below i have `post-category-id` and `post-id`. Is it possible to pass these params in dynamically. It tried to pass them as array or as a String, but this is not working.

In the example I want to `{{#link-to "post" params}}` where post is nested in post-category. My goal is to pass in params with the 2 context params needed.

```
// router
this.resource('post-categories', {path: 'post-categories/:post-category-id'}, function() {
  this.resource('post', {path: 'post/:post-id'})
});

// controller
...
  params: Em.computed(function() {
    return [1, 4]
  })
...

// template
{{#link-to "post" params}}
```

I tried to read in the source, but that didn't help too much.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would consider that the model to be used for one of the routes.  Your best bet is to use two dynamic properties.

```
{{link-to 'My Post' 'post' p1 p2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not as a single variable. You can, however, achieve your goal (if I understand it correctly) by passing in both values under the same object.

So in your example, you'd have to change your params property to something like this:

```
params: Em.computed(function() {
  return { params: { catId: 1, postId: 4 } };
})
```

And then pass in the params to the full path as two dynamic properties:

```
{{#link-to "post-categories.post" params.catId params.postId}}
```

Comment: My goal is to pass in only 1 variable that contains 0, 1, 2, ... params depending on what the route will expect. The expected params will always be right, that nothing to take care of.

Is it possible through transitionToRoute?

Comment: From what I can tell, `transitionToRoute` won't be any better. What are those params representing? It seems to me you could achieve what you're going for by sending in the top model of your resource tree that you're linking to, and handling the child params via model associations: `{{#link-to "post" post}}`. Then you can handle the post's param associations in each route you hit.

Comment: The params are respresenting the dynamic segments of the route. I am storing the routes in a seperate controller and want to enable the user to navigate to a route. I have the routeName + the dynamic parts, only are my dynamic parts in the form of a variable. This variable can be transformed into anything that would work, e.g. "1 3", "'1' '3'", [1,3], yet I tried these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my solution goes through an action on the controller.
In this action I check the length of my params and switch case `transitionToRoute` with the desired amount of dynamic parts. Though not verry DRY.

```
switch (params.length) {
  case 0: 
    this.transitionToRoute(route.get('routeName'))
  break;
  case 1: 
    this.transitionToRoute(route.get('routeName'), params[0])
  break;
  case 2: 
    this.transitionToRoute(route.get('routeName'), params[0], params[1])
  break;
  case 3: 
    this.transitionToRoute(route.get('routeName'), params[0], params[1], params[2])
}
```